# Angular authentication with Graphql

Tags: angular, graphql, ngrx

I'm working with SmartAdmin Angular template and I would to manage the authentication with Graphql. I already have the server side and with this mutation string and corrected credentials, I receive the token

```
mutation Login {
    Login (input: {
        username: "test",
        password: "test"
    }) {
        role
        jwtAuthToken
    }
}
```

But I've a problem, when I want to use this into a AuthService.
I start to explain from LoginComponent, where I've this method

```
login(){
   event.preventDefault();

   // get email and password values
   const email: string = this.form.get("email").value;
   const password: string = this.form.get("password").value;

   // trim values
   email.trim();
   password.trim();

   const payload = {
     email: email,
     password: password
   };

   this.store.dispatch(new LoginAction(payload));
}
```

I call the LoginAction and the AuthEffect intercepts the action

```
export class AuthEffects {
redirectUrl: string = '/home';
  loginUrl: string = '/auth/login';
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  login$ = this.actions$.pipe(
           ofType(actions.AuthActionTypes.LoginAction),
           tap((data: any) => {
           this.authService.login(data.payload.email, data.payload.password)
...
```

Now, in the AuthService I want use Graphql, but I've some problem with Observable 
This is my code in the service.

```
public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
this.apollo
  .mutate({
    mutation: gql`
        mutation Login {
          Login(input: { username: "${email}", password: "${password}" }) {
            role
            jwtAuthToken
            uuid
            username
          }
        }
      `
  })
  .subscribe(
    ({ data }) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      console.log("logged");
      return of(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("login error");
      if (error.graphQLErrors && error.graphQLErrors.length === 1) {
        return throwError(new Error(error.graphQLErrors[0].message));
      } else if (
        error.networkError &&
        error.networkError.error &&
        error.networkError.error.errors &&
        error.networkError.error.errors.length === 1
      ) {
        return throwError(
          new Error(error.networkError.error.errors[0].message)
        );
      } else {
        return throwError(new Error("Login error: " + error.message));
      }
    }
  );     
}
```

but I have an error, because in this case I don't have a return value. How can I return the User or error to the Effect, and complete the Effect to call Auth complete o failure?
Thanks